# ode integration in python versus mathematica results

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, precision, differential-equations

**Edit:**
So I found out that NDSolve for ODE is using Runge Kutta to solve the equations.
How can I use the Runge Kutta method on my python code to solve the ODE I have below?

From my post on [text files with float entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325258/text-files-with-float-entries-python), I was able to determine that `python` and `mathematica` immediately start diverging with a tolerance of 10 to the negative 6.

**End Edit**

For last few hours, I have been trying to figure out why my solutions in Mathematica and Python differ by `5000` something `km`.

I am led to believe one program has a higher error tolerance when simulating over millions of seconds in flight time.

My question is which program is more accurate, and if it isn't python, how can I adjust the precision?

With `Mathematica`, I am less than 10km away from `L4` where as with `Python` I am `5947` km away.

The codes are listed below:

`Python`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from numpy import linspace
from scipy.optimize import brentq

me = 5.974 * 10 ** (24)  #  mass of the earth                                     
mm = 7.348 * 10 ** (22)  #  mass of the moon                                      
G = 6.67259 * 10 ** (-20)  #  gravitational parameter                             
re = 6378.0  #  radius of the earth in km                                         
rm = 1737.0  #  radius of the moon in km                                          
r12 = 384400.0  #  distance between the CoM of the earth and moon                 
d = 300 #  distance the spacecraft is above the Earth                             
pi1 = me / (me + mm)
pi2 = mm / (me + mm)
mue = 398600.0  #  gravitational parameter of earth km^3/sec^2                    
mum = G * mm  #  grav param of the moon                                           
mu = mue + mum
omega = np.sqrt(mu / (r12 ** 3))

nu = -np.pi / 4  #  true anomaly  pick yourself                                   

xl4 = r12 / 2 - 4671  #  x location of L4                                         
yl4 = np.sqrt(3) / 2 * r12  #  y                                                  

print("The location of L4 is", xl4, yl4)

#  Solve for Jacobi's constant                                                    
def f(C):
    return (omega ** 2 * (xl4 ** 2 + yl4 ** 2) + 2 * mue / r12 + 2 * mum / r12
            + 2 * C)


c = brentq(f, -5, 0)

print("Jacobi's constant is",c)

x0 = (re + 200) * np.cos(nu) - pi2 * r12  #  x location of the satellite          
y0 = (re + 200) * np.sin(nu)  #  y location                                       

print("The satellite's initial position is", x0, y0)

vbo = (np.sqrt(omega ** 2 * (x0 ** 2 + y0 ** 2) + 2 * mue /
               np.sqrt((x0 + pi2 * r12) ** 2 + y0 ** 2) + 2 * mum /
               np.sqrt((x0 - pi1 * r12) ** 2 + y0 ** 2) + 2 * -1.21))

print("Burnout velocity is", vbo)

gamma = 0.4678 * np.pi / 180  #  flight path angle pick yourself                  

vx = vbo * (np.sin(gamma) * np.cos(nu) - np.cos(gamma) * np.sin(nu))
#  velocity of the bo in the x direction                                          
vy = vbo * (np.sin(gamma) * np.sin(nu) + np.cos(gamma) * np.cos(nu))
#  velocity of the bo in the y direction                                          

print("The satellite's initial velocity is", vx, vy)

#  r0 = [x, y, 0]                                                                 
#  v0 = [vx, vy, 0]                                                               
u0 = [x0, y0, 0, vx, vy, 0]


def deriv(u, dt):
return [u[3],  #  dotu[0] = u[3]                                                 
        u[4],  #  dotu[1] = u[4]                                                 
        u[5],  #  dotu[2] = u[5]                                                 
        (2 * omega * u[4] + omega ** 2 * u[0] - mue * (u[0] + pi2 * r12) /
         np.sqrt(((u[0] + pi2 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3) - mum *
         (u[0] - pi1 * r12) /
         np.sqrt(((u[0] - pi1 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3)),
        #  dotu[3] = that                                                        
        (-2 * omega * u[3] + omega ** 2 * u[1] - mue * u[1] /
         np.sqrt(((u[0] + pi2 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3) - mum * u[1] /
         np.sqrt(((u[0] - pi1 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3)),
        #  dotu[4] = that                                                        
        0]  #  dotu[5] = 0                                                       


dt = np.linspace(0.0, 6.0 * 86400.0, 2000000.0)  #  secs to run the simulation    
u = odeint(deriv, u0, dt)
x, y, z, x2, y2, z2 = u.T

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(x, y, z, color = 'r')
#  adding the Lagrange point                                                      
phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
xm = 2000 * np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta)) + xl4
ym = 2000 * np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta)) + yl4
zm = 2000 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(xm, ym, zm, color = '#696969', linewidth = 0)
ax.auto_scale_xyz([-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000])
#  adding the earth                                                               
phi = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
xm = 2000 * np.outer(np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta))
ym = 2000 * np.outer(np.sin(phi), np.sin(theta))
zm = 2000 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(phi)), np.cos(theta))
ax.plot_surface(xm, ym, zm, color = '#696969', linewidth = 0)
ax.auto_scale_xyz([-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000], [-8000, 385000])

plt.show()

#  The code below finds the distance between path and l4                          
my_x, my_y, my_z = (xl4, yl4, 0.0)

delta_x = x - my_x
delta_y = y - my_y
delta_z = z - my_z
distance = np.array([np.sqrt(delta_x ** 2 + delta_y ** 2 + delta_z ** 2)])

minimum = np.amin(distance)

print("Closet approach to L4 is", minimum)
```

`Mathematica`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
me = 5.974*10^(24);
mm = 7.348*10^(22);
G = 6.67259*10^(-20);
re = 6378;
rm = 1737;
r12 = 384400;

\[Pi]1 = me/(me + mm);
\[Pi]2 = mm/(me + mm);
M = me + mm;
\[Mu]1 = 398600;
\[Mu]2 = G*mm;
\[Mu] = \[Mu]1 + \[Mu]2;
\[CapitalOmega] = Sqrt[\[Mu]/r12^3];
\[Nu] = -\[Pi]/4;

xl4 = 384400/2 - 4671;
yl4 = Sqrt[3]/2*384400 // N;

Solve[\[CapitalOmega]^2*(xl4^2 + yl4^2) + 2 \[Mu]1/r12 + 
   2 \[Mu]2/r12 + 2*C == 0, C]
x = (re + 200)*Cos[\[Nu]] - \[Pi]2*r12 // N
y = (re + 200)*Sin[\[Nu]] // N

{{C -> -1.56824}}

-19.3098

-4651.35

vbo = Sqrt[\[CapitalOmega]^2*((x)^2 + (y)^2) + 
   2*\[Mu]1/Sqrt[(x + \[Pi]2*r12)^2 + (y)^2] + 
   2*\[Mu]2/Sqrt[(x - \[Pi]1*r12)^2 + (y)^2] + 2*(-1.21)]

10.8994

\[Gamma] = 0.4678*Pi/180;
vx = vbo*(Sin[\[Gamma]]*Cos[\[Nu]] - Cos[\[Gamma]]*Sin[\[Nu]]);
vy = vbo*(Sin[\[Gamma]]*Sin[\[Nu]] + Cos[\[Gamma]]*Cos[\[Nu]]);

r0 = {x, y, 0};
v0 = {vx, vy, 0}

{7.76974, 7.64389, 0}

s = NDSolve[{x1''[t] - 
      2*\[CapitalOmega]*x2'[t] - \[CapitalOmega]^2*
       x1[t] == -\[Mu]1/((Sqrt[(x1[t] + \[Pi]2*r12)^2 + 
             x2[t]^2])^3)*(x1[t] + \[Pi]2*
          r12) - \[Mu]2/((Sqrt[(x1[t] - \[Pi]1*r12)^2 + 
             x2[t]^2])^3)*(x1[t] - \[Pi]1*r12), 
    x2''[t] + 
      2*\[CapitalOmega]*x1'[t] - \[CapitalOmega]^2*
       x2[t] == -\[Mu]1/(Sqrt[(x1[t] + \[Pi]2*r12)^2 + x2[t]^2])^3*
       x2[t] - \[Mu]2/(Sqrt[(x1[t] - \[Pi]1*r12)^2 + x2[t]^2])^3*
       x2[t], x3''[t] == 0, x1[0] == r0[[1]], x1'[0] == v0[[1]], 
    x2[0] == r0[[2]], x2'[0] == v0[[2]], x3[0] == r0[[3]], 
    x3'[0] == v0[[3]]}, {x1, x2, x3}, {t, 0, 1000000}];

ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 10*24*3600}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]

g1 = ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 5.75*3600*24}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10000, 400000}, {-10000, 400000}}];
g2 = Graphics3D[{Blue, Opacity[0.6], Sphere[{-4671, 0, 0}, re]}];
g3 = Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[0.6], Sphere[{379729, 0, 0}, rm]}];
g4 = Graphics3D[{Black, Sphere[{xl4, yl4, 0}, 2000]}];
Show[g2, g1, g3, g4, Boxed -> False]


(*XYdata=Flatten[Table[Evaluate[{x1[t],x2[t],x3[t]}/.s],{t,5.5*24*\
3600,5.78*24*3600,1}],1];
X1Y1data=Flatten[Table[Evaluate[{x1'[t],x2'[t],x3'[t]}/.s],{t,5.5*24*\
3600,5.78*24*3600,1}],1];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["OrbitData.txt",XYdata,"CSV"];
Export["OrbVeloc.txt",X1Y1data,"CSV"];*)
```

Comment: my advice would be to find a problem with an exact analytic solution and solve it both ways.

Comment: You could try adjusting the `atol` and `rtol` arguments of `odeint` (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy.integrate.odeint).  But this won't tell you if the `odeint` solution is more or less accurate than the Mathematica solution.

Comment: one thing you might want to play with is explicitly telling NDSolve what method to use.  Both odeint and mathematica are dynamically/adaptively choosing solution methods so its unlikely youll ever get precisely the same results. Without studying the proble carefully its hard to say if the differece you see is significant or in the noise.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I changed the `atol` and `rtol` to `1e-14` but the trajectory remained unchanged at `5xxx` km away.

Comment: @george I found out the `NDSolve` use Runge Kutta.  How can I use Runge Kutta on python code to solve the ode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at this point your problem has reduced to just wanting to use Runge-Kutta, you can for example replace this line:

```
u = odeint(deriv, u0, dt)
```

with something like this:

```
#reverse the order of arguments
def deriv2(t,u):
    return deriv(u,t)

# initialize a 4th order Runge-Kutta ODE solver
solver = ode(deriv2).set_integrator('dopri5')
solver.set_initial_value(u0)
u = np.empty((len(dt), 6))
u[0,:] = u0
for ii in range(1,len(dt)):
    u[ii] = solver.integrate(dt[ii])
```

(+obviously replace the odeint import with ode).

Note that this is significantly slower for this type of ODE.

To use the dop853, use solver.set_integrator('dop853').

Comment: Maybe there is a way to have cython run the heavy computations to speed it up?

Comment: Yes, that might help, but I'm only starting to look into performance tuning. Remember that RK4 is a quite nicely-behaving solver (at least for non-stiff problems), and you probably don't need that many timesteps.

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote the def deriv part of the ode and it works now!  So the `Mathematica` plot and the `Python` agree.

```
def deriv(u, dt):
    return [u[3],  #  dotu[0] = u[3]                                                 
            u[4],  #  dotu[1] = u[4]                                                 
            u[5],  #  dotu[2] = u[5]                                                 
            (2 * omega * u[4] + omega ** 2 * u[0] - mue * (u[0] + pi2 * r12) /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] + pi2 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3) - mum *
             (u[0] - pi1 * r12) /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] - pi1 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3)),
            #  dotu[3] = that                                                        
            (-2 * omega * u[3] + omega ** 2 * u[1] - mue * u[1] /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] + pi2 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3) - mum * u[1] /
             np.sqrt(((u[0] - pi1 * r12) ** 2 + u[1] ** 2) ** 3)),
            #  dotu[4] = that                                                        
            0]  #  dotu[5] = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to check the accuracy could be this:

take a time where the 2 trajectories are sufficiently different from one another (the last time/point in the trajectory for example). Use this as the new starting point and integrate back in time to the initial time (or, if you prefer, integrate forward in time, but reverse the velocities of all bodies present in the simulation). The final point in this simulation should be (close to) your initial point in the original simulation. By comparing how close you actually get to your original initial point, you can judge how good python vs mathematica solver routines are.  My guess is that the Mathematica routines are much better, so all this Python thing is a waste of time.

Another way could be this:
With Mathematica what you get is an interpolating function which you can symbolically derive and then numerically evaluate its derivatives. Plug these values in the ODE at different points and see if they satisfy the ODE. Do something similar in python and compare the results.

Comment: Third option: move this question to the (almost) new http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ sister site , where cool MMA ideas are exchanged every day

Comment: I found the issue.  `NDSolve` use `runge kutta` for its integration.  I edited my post yesterday asking how this can be implemented with the `python` code.

Comment: how did you determine that?  It looks to me like the default is probably adams (same as odeint).  Frankly its an annoyance with mathematica  that there is usually no simple way to know what it chooses for automatic settings..you can however manually specify methods and see if any gives you significantly different results.