# Call Matlab's ODE45 from python

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to call Matlab's ode45 function from python just like MATLAB's isprime() function is called in the following python code

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
tf = eng.isprime(37)
print(tf)
```

but I don't really know how to implement the code in python.
I've tried

```
import matlab.engine

def  dydt(t,y):
              dydt= 2*y
              return dydt
          
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
T,Y=eng.ode45(dydt,[0, 20],[2, 0])
```

and it returned :

> line 73, in **call**
> out=_stdout, err=_stderr)
>
> TypeError: unsupported Python data type: function.

I've already installed the MATLAB Engine API for Python according to the following link
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html and tested it successfully using examples in the following link
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html .

I found the following thread that might be relevant
[Imitate ode45 function from MATLAB in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428140/imitate-ode45-function-from-matlab-in-python)
but from what I see they just used python's libraries to solve the ODEs and don't call the MATLAB's ODE45 from python. Maybe I just don't understand that correctly.

Could anyone help me make progress with that issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imitate ode45 function from MATLAB in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428140/imitate-ode45-function-from-matlab-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406331/how-to-run-a-matlab-code-on-python ?

Comment: @norok2, thank you I might eventually go for that. Maybe in order to refine my question: I would like to run MATLAB's ode45 just like the isprime() function is run in the following link:https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html

Comment: Have you tried `eng.ode45()`?

Comment: put a comma between the numbers: `T,Y=eng.ode45(vdp1,[0, 20],[2, 0])`, you are now in Python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducing the example from the [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bu04u19-1):

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.eval('tspan = [0 5];',nargout = 0)
eng.eval('y0 = 0;',nargout = 0)
t,y=eng.eval('ode45(@(t,y) 2*t, tspan, y0)',nargout = 2)
```

Now you can plot the results too:

```
eng.plot(t,y,'-o')
```

Comment: Actually, I am using the Spyder IDE that comes with the Anaconda package...
Could you explain what the eval() function does there? And also the (" term?

Comment: @FinX You are welcome. My bad, there was a typo in my answer.

Comment: @ UnbearableLightness Could you please explain why the eval() function is needed in this case? I ask because in the code i posted in my question above the isprime() function doesn't require the eval() function.

Comment: @FinX It is needed because of this: `TypeError: unsupported Python data type: function.` and `ode45()` requires a function which you could not pass otherwise.

Comment: @FinX norok2 is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

You could be using [`scipy.integrate.RK45()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html#scipy.integrate.RK45), or, possibly preferably, [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp):

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
def exponential_decay(t, y): return -0.5 * y
sol = solve_ivp(exponential_decay, [0, 10], [2, 4, 8])
print(sol.t)
# [  0.           0.11487653   1.26364188   3.06061781   4.85759374
#    6.65456967   8.4515456   10.        ]
print(sol.y)
# [[2.         1.88836035 1.06327177 0.43319312 0.17648948 0.0719045
#   0.02929499 0.01350938]
#  [4.         3.7767207  2.12654355 0.86638624 0.35297895 0.143809
#   0.05858998 0.02701876]
#  [8.         7.5534414  4.25308709 1.73277247 0.7059579  0.287618
#   0.11717996 0.05403753]]
```

(example from the official doc.)

Comment: thank you for your answer.  But aren't these SciPy libraries?
I am more looking for calling MATLAB's ode45 from python.

Comment: @FinX That is correct. If you are only after calling MATLAB code from Python, then the text of the question is quite misleading.