# Too many values to unpack in Scipy Integrate : solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

So I am using scipy.integrate's solve_ivp to solve a system of 4 first order coupled differential equations.
Here is the piece of code:

```
def bigF (a, b):
    return [f1(a, b), f2(a, b), f3(a, b), f4(a, b)]
X, Y = solve_ivp(bigF, (0.1, 15),[0.999, 0.003, -0.033, 0.067])
```

bigF is a collection of four functions, arguments being a('x') and b('y-array'), it is like y_0 ' = f1, y_1 ' = f2 and so on.
The second argument is a tuple of initial and final x, and the final argument is the initial values of the four y's.

I get the following error[full message]:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/Semester 6/Dissertation/Coding Part/inbuilt.py", line 11, in 
X, Y = solve_ivp(bigF, (0.1, 15),  [0.999, 0.003, -0.033, 0.067])
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)*

I have no idea what this means, google does not help much.

Comment: your function returning 4 values and you are reading it into only 2 variables.
One option is just use `x=your_function` or `a,b,c,d=your_function`

Comment: Please give the full error message and the place of the code that it points to. You are unpacking `b` somewhere but only give a pair of 2 variables on the left side. // Or it is already for the full call, `solve_ivp` returns one structure, you need to manually unpack its many fields.

Comment: @AmitNanaware Okay I got it.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I solved by using Z = solve_ivp()

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/65929146/3088138 for more details on using solve_ivp close to matlab's ode45

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone!