# Numpy:Finding difference between two files containing float values

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use Python to compute the difference between two text files and print the first value and location where they start to diverge.

I am not sure how to use `loadtxt`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.loadtxt("path/to/file", float)
b = np.loadtxt("path/to/file2", float)    
while np.absolute(a - b) !=0:


1
2
3
...
```

Not sure how to finish this?  Is the start correct?

Comment: What is in the text files?

Comment: @DavidRobinson a list of numbers.

Comment: @dustin: What *exactly* is in the text files? Post a sample of each.

Comment: @Blender so op for an example.

Comment: Are the files huge? If so, it may not pay to load the entire file just to find the first difference...

Comment: @unutbu 300,000 entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
idx = np.where(np.abs(a-b) > 1e-6)[0]
firstidx = idx[0]
```

to find the first index where the values in `a` and `b` differ by more than some nominal amount like `1e-6`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt("path/to/file", float)
b = np.loadtxt("path/to/file2", float)

idx = np.where(np.abs(a-b) > 1e-6)[0]
firstidx = idx[0]
print(firstidx, a[firstidx], b[firstidx])
```

---

Note that when dealing with floats, you rarely if ever want to compare with equality, such as with

```
np.abs(a-b) == 0
```

or the converse,

```
np.abs(a-b) != 0
```

because the inaccuracy of floating point representations can cause `a` and `b` to be slightly different even when their values should be *exactly* the same if their values were represented with infinite precision.

So use something like

```
np.abs(a-b) > 1e-6
```

instead. (Note that you have to choose a level of tolerance, e.g. 1e-6).

---

Here is a [simple example](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm) demonstrating the pitfall of comparing floats using equality:

```
In [10]: 1.2-1.0 == 0.2
Out[10]: False
```